# SQL get max date grouped by person from 2 identical tables (with different data)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a fairly simple model in MSSQL

Table1 (approximately 1000 rows)
Id, PersonId, Time

Table2 (approximately 10.000.000 rows)
Id, PersonId, Time

I need the latest entry (time) for each person based on data in these 2 tables. If it helps performance I can add that table1 is significantly smaller than Table2. There are no rules though, that the latest entry is in Table1 or in Table2.

It strikes me to be a fairly simple query, but i simply cannot crack it (without seemingly complex measures). Any inputs out there?

Comment: I know I really shouldnt bother, but i cant help myself. How would you know whether i didnt write the code myself? (Which I did)
Neither do you know how much research I put into this (which was a fair amount)
I beleive that a logical presentation of the problem was far easier to analyze than my rather complex solution query for this. I had 2 good answers which I am gratefull for

Comment: Hence the bold part above `post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working`. We only know what you include with your question and you should include your attempt as [so] is not an answer service. Please read [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @Igor, may i suggest you read the guidelines yourself. According to those Stack Overflow is all about questions and answers I understand that I have hurt your eyes, but I beleive I did nothing that conflicts with rules or guidelines. Besides the reading of the general guidelines may I also suggest that if you have nothing to contribute with, just stay away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `union all` & do aggregation :

```
select max(id), PersonId, max(time)
from (select t1.id, t1.PersonId, t1.Time 
      from table1 t1
      union all
      select t2.id, t2.PersonId, t2.Time 
      from table2 t2
     ) t
group by PersonId;
```

EDIT : You can use `row_number()` function with `ties` clase :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from ( . . .
     ) t
order by row_number() over (partition by PersonId order by time desc);
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, but the problem with that is the max(id). I need the row of the database that has the max time for each person

Comment: @Seniorudvikler. . . Then you need `row_number()` function.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `row_number()`, on the `union all`ed results:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from (select t1.id, t1.PersonId, t1.Time 
      from table1 t1
      union all
      select t2.id, t2.PersonId, t2.Time 
      from table2 t2
     ) t
order by row_number() over (partition by PersonId order by time desc);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The output is as expected (GREAT! :-) ) however, the performance on the sort is really bad (even with an index on time)